# Creating a new list when an element is found in a list in python

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-for-loop

The input from the user would be a list of random letters from a - z. So I made a list from a to z and I want to create a new list for each time a new letter is found also if a letter repeats I want it to be added to the new list already created for that specific letter. This is the code I wrote but I know that won't work.

```
newlist = []
    for letter in [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z]:
        for i in s:
            if letter == i:
                newlist.append(x)
```

Also if there's a completely different way I can do it, I'll like to know.

Comment: Your code doesn't run, and it's not clear from your description what you're trying to do.  Maybe if you explained it by giving an example of what you want `newlist` to look like at the end?  Are you just trying to count the number of times you see each letter?  (check out `collections.Counter` which will do that in one line!)

Comment: It sounds like the intention is what @Samwise describes. Perhaps an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Answer (score 0):

You could be more clear about the output you expect. But I assume you want to count the occurrences of each letter in the given input string. If you really want to break them into separate lists, for some contrived reason, that can be done too. I am arranging them into dictionaries keyed per included letter in the given string.

```py
s = "ababca"

counts = {}
for x in s:
    counts.setdefault(x, 0)
    counts[x] += 1

lists = {}
[lists.setdefault(x, []).append(x) for x in s]

print(counts) # Using the first method, with just counts.
print(lists) # Using the second method with list of the same letter.
```

which yields:

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
{'a': ['a', 'a', 'a'], 'b': ['b', 'b'], 'c': ['c']}
```

---

As an aside, if you want to iterate over letters, you don't have to create a list. These are the same:

```py
for l in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    print(l)

for l in "abc":
    print(l)
```